# Change default validates_size_of error message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Following is a model level validation on a file filed to validate the size

```
validates_size_of :inv_file, maximum: 25.megabyte, message: "Attachment size exceeds the allowable limit (25 MB)."
```

It works fine and when a file of size greater then 25MB is attached, following error message is displayed

```
"inv_attachemtns.inv_file": Attachment size exceeds the allowable limit (25 MB)."
```

I don't want this table_name.file_name ("inv_attachemtns.inv_file") to be displayed with error message

How can i remove this?

Comment: How are you rendering your errors into view?

Comment: Yes, i am rendering into view.

Comment: No @Arif. I am asking *how*. Can you add the view code that renders your error messages?

Comment: @invoice.errors.full_messages.join('\n')

Answer (score 0):

it depending on how are you render it in views

if you want to show error message with the field name (actually, you don't),you can use the `full_messages` to show error with the field name

```
- if @attachment.errors.any?
  %h2 Alert!
  %ul
    - @attachment.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
      %li= message
```

you will see error messages like

```
Alert!
"inv_attachemtns.inv_file": Attachment size exceeds the allowable limit (25 MB).
```

and if you want to hidden the field name ,you can just remove `full_messages` like

```
- if @attachment.errors.any?
  %h2 Alert!
  %ul
    - @attachment.errors.each do |field_name, message|
      %li= message
```

you will get what you want

```
Alert!
Attachment size exceeds the allowable limit (25 MB).
```